# setting up a basic mod_proxy virtual host

Tags: ubuntu, apache-2.2, mod-proxy

I'm trying to set up a basic virtual host to proxy all requests to test.local to a WEBrick server I have running on 127.0.0.1:8080 while keeping all requests to localhost going to my static files in /var/www. I'm running Ubuntu 10.04.

I have libapache2-mod-proxy-html installed and I have the module enabled with a2enmod proxy. I also have my virtual host enabled. However, whenever I go to test.local I always get a cryptic 500 server error and all my logs are telling me is:

```
[Thu Mar 03 01:43:10 2011] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

Here's my virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost test.local:80>
    LoadModule proxy_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy.so
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName test.local
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # prevents this folder from being proxied
    ProxyPass /static !

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Proxy *>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
```

and here's my settings for mod_proxy:

```
<IfModule mod_proxy.c>
        #turning ProxyRequests on and allowing proxying from all may allow
        #spammers to use your proxy to send email.

        ProxyRequests Off

        <Proxy *>
        # default settings
                #AddDefaultCharset off
                #Order deny,allow
                #Deny from all
                ##Allow from .example.com

        AddDefaultCharset off
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        # Enable/disable the handling of HTTP/1.1 "Via:" headers.
        # ("Full" adds the server version; "Block" removes all outgoing Via: headers)
        # Set to one of: Off | On | Full | Block

        ProxyVia On
</IfModule>
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Looks like you're not loading the `mod_proxy_http` module (which is needed to proxy to HTTP servers). I don't have Ubuntu 10.04 in front of me, but IIRC it's something like:

```
sudo a2enmod proxy_http
```

Comment: I have both proxy_http and proxy_html enabled and restarted apache but now I'm getting a 503 error. Here's the logs from right after I restarted with 3 refreshes on firefox:

Comment: [Thu Mar 03 12:25:29 2011] [error] (111)Connection refused: proxy: HTTP: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8080 (localhost) failed
[Thu Mar 03 12:25:29 2011] [error] ap_proxy_connect_backend disabling worker for (localhost)
[Thu Mar 03 12:26:05 2011] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)
[Thu Mar 03 12:26:10 2011] [error] proxy: HTTP: disabled connection for (localhost)

Comment: Actually, all of a sudden it started working. Thank you.

Comment: In my case, proxy_ajp was missing (we use AJP to connect with tomcat).

Comment: u just saved my life @ThomasFerrisNicolaisen

Answer (score 2):

The above answer didn't help for me as I was receiving the same error as in the author's comment in the selected answer. However, I did find the following post and change which solved my problem:

`sudo /usr/sbin/setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1`

Source: http://allscm.com/archives/apache2-proxy-disabled-connection-on-localhost.html

Comment: CentOS / RedHat / Fedora has SELinux. Ubuntu does not.

Comment: Oh my, excellent point. I missed the [ubuntu] tag on the original post, only now seeing that years later. I was on CentOS 6 at the time I ran into this problem, thus my inaccurate answer here.