# Trying to get Apache and nodejs to play nice together, getting "setsebool: SELinux is disabled."?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, selinux, node.js

I am running Ubuntu, and an Apache server.
I wanted to try out nodejs, and I wanted to run it through a virtualhost on Apache.
I read this article and tried to follow the instructions:
http://thatextramile.be/blog/2012/01/hosting-a-node-js-site-through-apache

I set everything up, but Apache was throwing 500 errors, which seems to be something like this situation:
[setting up a basic mod_proxy virtual host](https://serverfault.com/questions/242650/setting-up-a-basic-mod-proxy-virtual-host)

I tried running this command:
`sudo /usr/sbin/setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1`

In order to get that command working, I had to install this:
`sudo apt-get install policycoreutils`

But then when I tried the command, I get this error message:
`setsebool:  SELinux is disabled.`

All I want to do is be able to forward requests to `nodejs.mydomain.com` to a nodejs daemon running on port 8000.

How do I enable `setsebool`, or alternatively is there another way that I can get nodejs peacefully coexisting with an Apache server running on port 80?

Comment: You are trying to alter the SELinux configuration with `setsebool`. Why do you think it’s a SELinux problem? Are there any AVC denials in the system log? If SELinux is disabled… well, it’s disabled.

Comment: I don't know anything about SELinux, or how to enable/disable it. I am only using this command because it was the most promising-sounding fix to the error I was getting about forwarding my requests to `localhost:8000`.  The error messages in my apache error.log are similar to this one: `[Fri Feb 15 08:50:35 2013] [warn] proxy: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.`

Comment: It’s not SELinux…

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I solved this myself.
I apparently misread `mod_proxy_http` as `mod_proxy_html` every time I looked at the article.

After enabling the proper **proxy_http** module, everything started working.

Stupid PEBCAK error, but I will leave the question here in case anyone else is looking to solve the original problem.